# Calculating a current day 7 day active user with BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

To calculate the current day active user should be simple if I'm not mistaken. Simply take today and x days back (7-day-active would be 6 back) and then count the distinct IDs. I have the following query for a 2 day active user:

```
WITH allTables AS (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    event.date,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id as users
  FROM `dataset.app_events_intraday_20170407`
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    event.date,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id as users
  FROM `dataset.app_events_20170406`
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
) SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS unique,
   COUNT(users) as total
FROM allTables
```

This is for a 2-day active but for a 7day or 30day I would just union all those tables on. Is this correct or would this need modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using UNION ALL you should try to use [`Querying Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)

Try something like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH allTables AS (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    event.date,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `dataset.app_events_intraday_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170407' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    event.date,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `dataset.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170407' 
) 
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS unique,
  COUNT(users) AS total
FROM allTables
```

You can use below for `WHERE` clause to make it more generic

```sql
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
   BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)) 
   AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

Also please note: I changed `app_id` in `user_dim.app_info.app_id` to `app_instance_id` as I thought it was typo on your side  - but I can be wrong

Comment: I have a lot of tables so the union all is required, the wildcard pulls too much data.

Comment: what you mean? it will take only those table and columns that are referenced!

Comment: I'm running queries that use the wildcard right now and they limit the rows they're selecting yet take forever to process.

Comment: I missed the section with _table_Suffix... I did not know about that wow.

Comment: i am glad you read it in full now :o) - so does it work now for you? btw. in my answer  - i provided link to respective doc

Comment: Taking a look now. If only I knew about that function a few months ago lol

Comment: use SO more :o)

Comment: It seems to be returning the same data no matter how far I change `BETWEEN 'datehere'`

Comment: please do it carefully! this is something that works! so just do it carefully! i recommend for testing to use version on the top - `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170407'` and just change dates as strings - i think in this case it is easier to not to make extra mistakes

Comment: I see the issue now, is there a way to include both `app_events_intraday` and just `app_events` ?

Comment: I got you. Thanks for this... definitely a good step in the right direction.

Comment: see update answer  - i think i got it now with both set of tables

Comment: That seems to be working now. I don't think it's worth opening a new question for but how would you query for just a 1 day active? `INTERVAL 1 DAY`?

Comment: Just use same day for start and end - for example `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170407' AND '20170407'`

Comment: And that should be updating throughout the day too I would assume?

Comment: what do you mean? clarify

Comment: If I remember correctly, 1-day active users are everyone from today. So basically it will update as more users get rows inserted.

Comment: Awesome, you have no idea how much you just changed my BigQuery life. Thank you so much :D

Comment: glad we did it - sometimes such words cost more than any votes - thank you!