# 7-day user count: Big-Query self-join to get date range and count?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My Google Firebase event data is integrated to BigQuery and I'm trying to fetch from here one of the info that Firebase gives me automatically: 1-day, 7-day, 28-day user count.

1-day count is quite straightforward

```
SELECT
  "1-day" as period,
  events.event_date,
  count(distinct events.user_pseudo_id) as uid
FROM
  `your_path.events_*` as events
WHERE events.event_name = "session_start"
group by events.event_date
```

with a neat result like

```
period   event_date  uid
1-day    20190609    5
1-day    20190610    7
1-day    20190611    5
1-day    20190612    7
1-day    20190613    37
1-day    20190614    73
1-day    20190615    52
1-day    20190616    36
```

But to me it gets complicated when I try to **count for each day how many unique users I had in the previous 7 days**
From the above query, I know my target value for day 20190616 will be 142, by filtering 7 days and removing the group by condition.

The solution I tried is direct self join (and variations that didnt change the result)

```
SELECT
  "7-day" as period,
  events.event_date,
  count(distinct user_events.user_pseudo_id) as uid
FROM
  `your_path.events_*` as events,
  `your_path.events_*` as user_events
WHERE user_events.event_name = "session_start"
  and PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", events.event_date) between DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", user_events.event_date), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", user_events.event_date) #one day in the first table should correspond to 7 days worth of events in the second
  and events.event_date = "20190616" #fixed date to check
group by events.event_date
```

Now, I know I'm barely setting any join conditions, but if any I expected to produce cross joins and huge results. Instead, the count this way is 70, which is a lot lower than expected. Furthermore, I can set INTERVAL 2 DAY and the result does not change.

I'm clearly doing something very wrong here, but I also thought that the way I'm doing it is very rudimental, and there must be a smarter way to accomplish this.

I have checked [Calculating a current day 7 day active user with BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283945/calculating-a-current-day-7-day-active-user-with-bigquery) but the explicit cross join here is with event_dim which definition I'm unsure about

---

Cheched the solution provided at [Rolling 90 days active users in BigQuery, improving preformance (DAU/MAU/WAU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852357/rolling-90-days-active-users-in-bigquery-improving-preformance-dau-mau-wau/49866033#49866033) as suggested by comment.
The solution seemed sound at first but has some problems the more recent the day is. Here's the query using COUNT(DISTINCT) that I adapted to my case

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(event_date, INTERVAL i DAY) date_grp
 , COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) unique_90_day_users
 , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(i<29,user_pseudo_id,null)) unique_28_day_users
 , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(i<8,user_pseudo_id,null)) unique_7_day_users
 , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(i<2,user_pseudo_id,null)) unique_1_day_users
FROM (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date) as event_date, user_pseudo_id
  FROM `your_path_here.events_*`
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date))=2019
  GROUP BY 1, 2
), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 90)) i
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY date_grp
```

and here is the result for the latest days (consider data starts 23rd May) where you can appreciate that the result is wrong

```
row_num   date_grp     90-day  28-day  7-day   1-day
114       2019-06-16   273     273     273     210
115       2019-06-17   78      78      78      78
```

so in the last day this count for 90-day,28-day,7day is only considering the very same day instead of all the days before.
It's not possible for 90-day count on the 17th June to be 78 if the 1-day on the 16th June was higher.

Comment: Do you have a calendar\date table that you can use? If so, you can skip the CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438

Comment: I tried the solution linked by Felipe. Unfortunately I cant meet some of the conditions: can't be sure there wont be gaps in the days and HLL_COUNT shows no result. Will post edit asap

Answer (score 2):

This is **AN** answer to my same question.
My means are rudimentary as I'm not extremely familiar with BQ shortcuts and some advanced functions, but the result is still correct.
I hope others will be able to integrate with better queries.

```
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT i as event_date
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2019-05-24', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) i
)
, ptd_dates as (
  SELECT DISTINCT "90-day" as day_category, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date) AS event_date, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(event_date, INTERVAL i-1 DAY)) as ptd_date
  FROM dates,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 90)) i
  UNION ALL
  SELECT distinct "28-day" as day_category, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date) AS event_date, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(event_date, INTERVAL i-1 DAY)) as ptd_date
  FROM dates,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 29)) i
  UNION ALL
  SELECT distinct "7-day" as day_category, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date) AS event_date, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(event_date, INTERVAL i-1 DAY)) as ptd_date
  FROM dates,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 7)) i
  UNION ALL
  SELECT distinct "1-day" as day_category, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date) AS event_date, FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",event_date) as ptd_date
  FROM dates
)


SELECT event_date,
  sum(IF(day_category="90-day",unique_ptd_users,null)) as count_90_day ,
  sum(IF(day_category="28-day",unique_ptd_users,null)) as count_28_day,
  sum(IF(day_category="7-day",unique_ptd_users,null)) as count_7_day,
  sum(IF(day_category="1-day",unique_ptd_users,null)) as count_1_day
from (
SELECT ptd_dates.day_category
  , ptd_dates.event_date
  , COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) unique_ptd_users
FROM ptd_dates,
  `your_path_here.events_*` events,
  unnest(events.event_params) e_params
WHERE ptd_dates.ptd_date = events.event_date
GROUP BY ptd_dates.day_category
  , ptd_dates.event_date)
group by event_date
order by 1,2,3
```

As per suggestion from ECris, I first defined a calendar table to use: this contains 4 categories of PTDs (period to date). Each is generated from basic elements: this should scale linearly as it's not querying the event dataset and therefore does not have gaps.

Then the join is made with events, where the join condition shows how for each date I'm counting distinct users in all related days in the period.

The results are correct.